# How to empty all tables in Apache Derby?

Tags: sql, derby, referential-integrity

I want to empty all tables in Apache Derby. I do not want to remove all the tables, just their contents. This cannot be done easily with a simple set of DELETE statements, as the tables can contain circular references.

In PostgreSQL/H2/Oracle, you can turn referential integrity off and then truncate all tables. This does not seem to work in Derby.

Any hints?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: No. I gave up on derby..

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be to delete the entire database, then re-create a fresh new empty database and re-create the database schema (tables, indexes, constraints, etc.)

Use a tool like "dblook" to capture the current database schema as a set of SQL statements to make it easy to re-create the schema in a fresh new database: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.10/tools/rtoolsdblookexamples.html